# Calling Perl function from C produce crash

Tags: c, multithreading, perl

I have a Perl library written in C and inside XS file I declared callback function to call Perl functions from C code. When call this function from C code (multithreaded):

```
char *
callbackfunc(void *fun, char **args)
{
  dSP;

  int count,i;
  char *s;

  ENTER;
  SAVETMPS;

  PUSHMARK(SP);
  for(i=0;args[i];++i) {
    XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSVpv(args[i],0)));
  }
  PUTBACK;

  count = call_sv(fun,G_SCALAR|G_EVAL);

  SPAGAIN;

  s = NULL;
  if(count > 1)
    croak("callback may return only single value\n");
  if(count==1) {
    s = strdup(POPp);
  }

  PUTBACK;
  FREETMPS;
  LEAVE;    
  return s;
}
```

I get crash at *dSP* macro:

```
#0 callbackfunc (fun=0x2416a58, args=0x7f3a0cfa9a10) at MyLibrary.xs:24
24 dSP;
```

In disassembler it looks like some thread specific data not found:

```
push  %r15
push  %r14
mov   %rdi,%r14
push  %r13
mov   %rsi,%r13
push  %r12
push  %rbp
push  %rbx
sub   $0x8,%rsp
mov   0x2015dd(%rip),%rbx
mov   (%rbx),%edi
callq 0x7f3a0e37f550 <pthread_getspecific@plt>
mov   (%rbx),%esi
mov   (%rax),%r15 // here is crash because %rax is 0x0
```

Comment: This line is very suspicious: `for(i=0;args[i];++i)`, do you mean `for(i=0;i<args;++i)`?

Comment: @AlterMann maybe you are right, but currently it doesn't hit it because it crash far early.

Comment: Hooray for using `++i` instead of `i++`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to tell your thread about the current Perl interpreter. The [`perlembed` man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html#Maintaining-multiple-interpreter-instances) says:

> PERL_SET_CONTEXT(interp) should also be called whenever interp is used by a thread that did not create it (using either perl_alloc(), or the more esoteric perl_clone()).

Also note that calling Perl from C is not thread-safe. Make sure that proper locking is in place.

**EDIT:** If you didn't create the interpreter yourself, you can get a `void *` to the interpreter via the macro `PERL_GET_CONTEXT`. If you're only using a single interpreter, you could add some code to the XS boot section to store this value in a global. If you have multiple interpreters (or want to support `fork` on Windows), you have to track the current interpreter when registering your callback.

Comment: I added some details: this code declared inside Perl library. So I don't create interpreter myself, it is already created. How I could set this context for such case?